# This is a calculator that calculates the score for egyptain ig students, it always keeps crashing when pressing the button

Tags: java, android

this is my code, This is a calculator that calculates the score for egyptian igcse students, it always keeps crashing when pressing the button calculate

```
 package com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText stroletxt, aoletxt, boletxt, coletxt, aasetxt, basetxt, casetxt, dasetxt, straletxt, aaletxt, baletxt, caletxt, daletxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);


    stroletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stroletxt);

    aoletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aoletxt);

    boletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.boletxt);

    coletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coletxt);

    aasetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aasetxt);

    basetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.basetxt);


    casetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.casetxt);

    dasetxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dasetxt);

    straletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.straletxt);

    aaletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aaletxt);

    baletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.baletxt);

    caletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caletxt);

    daletxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.daletxt);


    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);




}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int viewId = view.getId();


    String stroletxtz= stroletxt.getText().toString();
    int stroletxtt=Integer.parseInt(stroletxtz);

    String aoletxtz = aoletxt.getText().toString();
    int aoletxtt = Integer.parseInt(aoletxtz);

    String boletxtz = boletxt.getText().toString();
    int boletxtt=Integer.parseInt(boletxtz);

    String coletxtz = coletxt.getText().toString();
    double coletxtt = Integer.parseInt(coletxtz);

    String aasetxtz = aasetxt.getText().toString();
    int aasetxtt = Integer.parseInt(aasetxtz);

    String basetxtz = basetxt.getText().toString();
    int basetxtt = Integer.parseInt(basetxtz);


    String casetxtz = casetxt.getText().toString();
    double casetxtt = Integer.parseInt(casetxtz);

    String dasetxtz = dasetxt.getText().toString();
    int dasetxtt = Integer.parseInt(dasetxtz);

    String straletxtz = straletxt.getText().toString();
    int straletxtt = Integer.parseInt(straletxtz);

    String aaletxtz = aaletxt.getText().toString();
    int aaletxtt = Integer.parseInt(aaletxtz);

    String baletxtz = baletxt.getText().toString();
    int baletxtt = Integer.parseInt(baletxtz);

    String caletxtz = caletxt.getText().toString();
    double caletxtt = Integer.parseInt(caletxtz);


    String daletxtz = aaletxt.getText().toString();
    int daletxtt = Integer.parseInt(daletxtz);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int) (((stroletxtt * 100 ) + (aoletxtt * 95 )+(boletxtt*85)+(coletxtt*67.5)+(aasetxtt*95)+(basetxtt*85)+(casetxtt*67.5)+(dasetxtt*60)+(straletxtt*100)+(aaletxtt*95)+(baletxtt*85)+(caletxtt*67.5)+(daletxtt*60))/(stroletxtt+boletxtt+coletxtt+aasetxtt+basetxtt+casetxtt+dasetxtt+straletxtt+aaletxtt+baletxtt+caletxtt+daletxtt)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

this is what my logcat says when the app is debugged

```
    12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator, PID: 3908
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5d
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:286)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-29 20:39:07.151 3908-3908/com.igcalc.karim.igcsecalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i hope someone tell me how this should be fixed

Comment: post your layout files.

Comment: that crash isn't really relevant to layout files.

Comment: Resource Not Found is strongly diagnostic.  Where do you define resource 0x5D?

Comment: Hey - you are getting that error because you are passing int value to the Toast.makeText() method. The only int values that you are allowed to pass there are string references from your R file (f.e. R.string.some_text). If you want to display a number, wrap the value that you want to display with: String.valueOf (your_value_here).

Answer (score 1):

you have to change this line:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int) (((stroletxtt * 100 ) + (aoletxtt * 95 )+(boletxtt*85)+(coletxtt*67.5)+(aasetxtt*95)+(basetxtt*85)+(casetxtt*67.5)+(dasetxtt*60)+(straletxtt*100)+(aaletxtt*95)+(baletxtt*85)+(caletxtt*67.5)+(daletxtt*60))/(stroletxtt+boletxtt+coletxtt+aasetxtt+basetxtt+casetxtt+dasetxtt+straletxtt+aaletxtt+baletxtt+caletxtt+daletxtt)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to be:

```
int value = (int) (((stroletxtt * 100 ) + (aoletxtt * 95 )+(boletxtt*85)+(coletxtt*67.5)+(aasetxtt*95)+(basetxtt*85)+(casetxtt*67.5)+(dasetxtt*60)+(straletxtt*100)+(aaletxtt*95)+(baletxtt*85)+(caletxtt*67.5)+(daletxtt*60))/(stroletxtt+boletxtt+coletxtt+aasetxtt+basetxtt+casetxtt+dasetxtt+straletxtt+aaletxtt+baletxtt+caletxtt+daletxtt));
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(value), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

also remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` from inside `onClick`, that makes no sense!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove below from `onClick(View view)`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Also inside `onClick` put check and move all text getting code inside `if`

```
if(viewId == R.id.calculate){

    String stroletxtz= stroletxt.getText().toString();
    int stroletxtt=Integer.parseInt(stroletxtz);

    String aoletxtz = aoletxt.getText().toString();
    int aoletxtt = Integer.parseInt(aoletxtz);

    String boletxtz = boletxt.getText().toString();
    int boletxtt=Integer.parseInt(boletxtz);

    String coletxtz = coletxt.getText().toString();
    double coletxtt = Integer.parseInt(coletxtz);

    String aasetxtz = aasetxt.getText().toString();
    int aasetxtt = Integer.parseInt(aasetxtz);

    String basetxtz = basetxt.getText().toString();
    int basetxtt = Integer.parseInt(basetxtz);


    String casetxtz = casetxt.getText().toString();
    double casetxtt = Integer.parseInt(casetxtz);

    String dasetxtz = dasetxt.getText().toString();
    int dasetxtt = Integer.parseInt(dasetxtz);

    String straletxtz = straletxt.getText().toString();
    int straletxtt = Integer.parseInt(straletxtz);

    String aaletxtz = aaletxt.getText().toString();
    int aaletxtt = Integer.parseInt(aaletxtz);

    String baletxtz = baletxt.getText().toString();
    int baletxtt = Integer.parseInt(baletxtz);

    String caletxtz = caletxt.getText().toString();
    double caletxtt = Integer.parseInt(caletxtz);


    String daletxtz = aaletxt.getText().toString();
    int daletxtt = Integer.parseInt(daletxtz);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (int) (((stroletxtt * 100 ) + (aoletxtt * 95 )+(boletxtt*85)+(coletxtt*67.5)+(aasetxtt*95)+(basetxtt*85)+(casetxtt*67.5)+(dasetxtt*60)+(straletxtt*100)+(aaletxtt*95)+(baletxtt*85)+(caletxtt*67.5)+(daletxtt*60))/(stroletxtt+boletxtt+coletxtt+aasetxtt+basetxtt+casetxtt+dasetxtt+straletxtt+aaletxtt+baletxtt+caletxtt+daletxtt) + ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```